# The static file is not loaded in the bootstrap template. Django app

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-staticfiles

In my purchased bootstrap template, static files are not loaded (only some they display correctly). What is this error caused by? How can I solve it?

I use the latest version of django and python3.For other templates, there was never a similar problem. When I choose the 'insert' option everything looks fine.
[image]

My folder structure:

```
-app
    -__pycache__
    -migrations
    -static
        -assets
            -svg
                -illustrations
                    -main-hero.svg
    -templates
-app_rama
manage.py
db
```

Example:

```
{% load static %}
[...]
<!-- SVG Background -->
<div id="SVGMainHero" class="col-lg-9 col-xl-7 svg-preloader d-none d-lg-block position-absolute top-0 right-0 pr-0" style="margin-top: 105.6px;">
  <figure class="ie-main-hero">
    <img class="js-svg-injector" src="{% static 'assets/svg/illustrations/main-hero.svg' %}" alt="Image Description" <!-- DO NOT SEE THIS PHOTOS -->
         data-img-paths='[
           {"targetId": "#SVGMainHeroImg1", "newPath": "{% static 'assets/img/750x750/img2.jpg' %}"}
         ]'
         data-parent="#SVGMainHero">
  </figure>
</div>
[...]
<!-- End SVG Background -->
```

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app_rama.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_rama.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Raport from my Browswer:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1776 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1777 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1778 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1775 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1776 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/jquery-migrate/dist/jquery-migrate.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1777 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(index):1778 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
hs.megamenu.js:999 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.megamenu.js:999
(anonymous) @ hs.megamenu.js:999
jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:1
    at jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:1
jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.validate.min.js:4
    at jquery.validate.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.validate.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.validate.min.js:4
jquery.fancybox.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function
    at jquery.fancybox.min.js:11
    at jquery.fancybox.min.js:12
(anonymous) @ jquery.fancybox.min.js:11
(anonymous) @ jquery.fancybox.min.js:12
slick.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at slick.js:25
    at slick.js:28
(anonymous) @ slick.js:25
(anonymous) @ slick.js:28
hs.core.js:176 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.core.js:176
(anonymous) @ hs.core.js:176
hs.header.js:2194 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.header.js:2194
(anonymous) @ hs.header.js:2194
hs.unfold.js:632 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.unfold.js:632
(anonymous) @ hs.unfold.js:632
hs.focus-state.js:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.focus-state.js:37
(anonymous) @ hs.focus-state.js:37
hs.malihu-scrollbar.js:102 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.malihu-scrollbar.js:102
(anonymous) @ hs.malihu-scrollbar.js:102
hs.validation.js:131 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.validation.js:131
(anonymous) @ hs.validation.js:131
hs.fancybox.js:181 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.fancybox.js:181
(anonymous) @ hs.fancybox.js:181
hs.slick-carousel.js:396 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.slick-carousel.js:396
(anonymous) @ hs.slick-carousel.js:396
hs.show-animation.js:111 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.show-animation.js:111
(anonymous) @ hs.show-animation.js:111
hs.svg-injector.js:85 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.svg-injector.js:85
(anonymous) @ hs.svg-injector.js:85
hs.go-to.js:166 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at hs.go-to.js:166
(anonymous) @ hs.go-to.js:166
(index):1804 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):1804
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you remember to run `collectstatic`? It's difficult to help because you haven't provided any configuration or logs to debug the problem, e.g. your settings for static files, server config to serve static files, output from your server logs/developer tools.

Comment: How do you run 'collectstatic'? I have never done it, but all applications worked properly (with the same settings)

Comment: You've got `DEBUG = True` so you don't need to run `collectstatic` at the moment. When you do deploy, see the [static files docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/) and the [deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#deployment) section for info about collectstatic.

Comment: I've added a short project structure. If the location of all files is needed, I will add more immediately.  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/svg/illustrations/main-hero.svg' <- returns '[26/Mar/2019 16:07:28] "GET /assets/svg/illustrations/main-hero.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 2215'

Comment: The `{% static %}` tag will only work in Django templates. Seeing `%7B%%20static%20'` in the console output makes it look as if you are including it elsewhere (e.g. in static js files). In js files, you could hardcode `/static/assets/svg/...`, or you might be able to use a relative URL e.g. `../svg/...`.

Comment: 1) Something is wrong with generated urls: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'assets`, so your code, loading js has errors  2) the image is not listed in given error log 3) your settings.py is missing `STATIC_ROOT` 4) you don't seem to have `vendors` folder within `static`.

Comment: Can I ask you for an example of how to solve this problem? Something like that '/static/assets/svg/...; in django return [26/Mar/2019 16:40:14] "GET /assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2221
Not Found: /assets/vendor/svg-injector/dist/svg-injector.min.js.

Comment: If you have `NOT Found: /assets/vendor/svg-injector/dist/svg-injector.min.js`, then you need to find the reference to that file and add the `/static/` prefix as I suggested. If you still have issues after making the changes, then make sure you save, restart the server and clear your browser cache to avoid caching issues.